# How to set padding in Textarea element (background-image bug)

Tags: css, html, textarea, background-image

**Goal:** In the current demo, theres a padding between the last word in the textarea field and the bottom border (the bottom border is realized through a "background" property).

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/7vaf1th8/336/

Thats how it looks like (And its correct, thats exactly what I want!):

[image]

In Webinspector:
[image]

**Problem:** As soon as I focus into the textarea, hit Enter and type some characters in, the characters are far too low near the bottom border (because the padding-bottom gets ignored), it looks like this (Which is wrong):

[image]

In Webinspector:
[image]

I've tried to set a calc(100%+7px) background position, to keep the space / padding between the bottom border and the characters, but no attempt was  successful.

**How can I remain the padding / space between the text and the bottom border while typing? (without disregarding/loosing/deleting the "background" property (border on the bottom), because I need it?)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it on my own now.
Ive created a parent class for the parent element, changed the background propertys to this parent element and deleted it on the child(textarea) element.

Now the padding works as expected.

Note: It seems to be a fact, after reading similar questions, that padding is not working in webkit on textareas "as expected". It doesnt seem to be a bug, just the way webkit handles padding when the scrollbar starts to appear on the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

in the `.form-group .form-control` you can change the padding to 0px and it will remove that extra: https://jsfiddle.net/7vaf1th8/349/

```
.form-group .form-control {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#66bb6a, #66bb6a), linear-gradient(rgba(165, 181, 203, .5), rgba(165, 181, 203, .5));
  background-size: 0 2px, 100% 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom, center calc(100%);
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background 0s ease-out;
  float: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It seems like I haven't made the question clear enough. The goal is not to remove the padding, the goal is to remain the space/padding even when the cursor is in the textarea window and something is typed in. Currently the space (padding) between the letters and the bottom border is not remained after something is typed in (the padding seems to be ignored). Thats the problem. I've edited the question to make it more clear.